# PHP, reading 8 byte integers from a MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a BINARY(40) column in a MySQL and there I store 5 8 byte integers. I am trying to read those numbers in PHP one by one:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT data FROM list WHERE id=".$id);
$mysql_array = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$list = str_split($mysql_array["data"], 8);
for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++)
    echo $list[$i]."<br/>";
```

Instead of the numbers I expect, weird symbols are printed. How can I convert those numbers from binary strings to integers?

Comment: Can you show the output of the "weird symbols" that are printed?

Comment: show the code how you store the integers.

Comment: @rink.attendant.6: There are many '�' one after another.

Comment: You're converting the numbers to strings when you return them, you'll need to convert them back, but unless you've got a 64 bit install of PHP that's not going to be easy without using a big number library to handle the calculations.

Comment: @scragar: is there any easy way to do this, for example by using BC?

Comment: You shouldn't be trying to store more than 1 datum in a column anyway.  Why not have five columns, each holding a single 8 byte integer?  As to your problem, a 64 bit build should be able to handle 64 bit (signed) integers.  Unsigned integers and/or 32 bit builds will require use of a bignum library such as BCMath and being prepared to accept the performance hit.

Comment: @GordonM: I am saving 50% space by storing them on the same column. I don't care too much about performance if it's 5-10 times slower, but I can't accept crazy numbers like 100 times slower.

Comment: @Luka Is space really so constrained that a few bytes per row matter that much?  Last I checked storage is dirt cheap.  Besides, it's not a matter of performance or storage, it's a matter of correctness.  I've had enough experience with databases to know that trying to put more than one datum in a column is almost always a terrible idea that will inevitably come back to haunt you

Comment: @GordonM: I see your point, and I don't have much experience in databases... In one table, if I store the numbers the way I do, I can save 1MB per day. This is not much and I will rethink my decision. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, because of the way you're storing the numbers, this code will only work if you've got 64 bit support, otherwise you'll have to look at a bc replacement, shouldn't be too difficult:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $bin_str = $list[$i];
    $int_val = 0;
    for ($j = 0; $j < 8; ++$j) {
        $byte_val = ord(substr($bin_str, $j, 1));
        // push the next byte onto our integer:
        $int_val = ($int_val << 8) + $byte_val;
    }
    echo $int_val;
}
```

EDIT: In all likelyhood this is a BC equiv, I'm unable to test it at the moment though, however the logic remains unchanged.

```
for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $bin_str = $list[$i];
    $bc_val = '0';
    for ($j = 0; $j < 8; ++$j) {
        $byte_val = ord(substr($bin_str, $j, 1));
        // push the next byte onto our integer:
        $bc_val = bcadd(bcmul($bc_val, 256, 0), "$byte_val", 0);
    }
    echo $bc_val;
}
```

Comment: I have a 32 bit version of PHP. After running this code, I didn't got the results I expected, but I at least got numbers. I will look into BC more.

Comment: @Luka, I've edited it to include a BC version with the same logic, could you check it?

Comment: I am getting some 64bit numbers, but the numbers are not the ones stored in the database. I will try to see if the error is on my part. Anyway, thanks for the helping me out!

Comment: It's possibly the endianness of the numbers, could you get the hex for both numbers and compare?

Comment: This is why more than one datum per column is a bad idea :)

Comment: @GordonM I'd argue this is more about storing integers as strings, rather than a native integer type, if it was a native integer MySQL would handle endianness and converting to a string of the number.

Comment: It doesn't work, but I understand your logic. In C/C++ such a thing is sooo easy but in PHP is such a pain, that's why I can't get along with PHP...

Comment: @Luka, PHP has a very different approach to memory and such than C, in C everything has a defined type(even things without a type are still considered to be of the type void) and casting is typically the way to convert binary data between types. In PHP you don't deal with strong types, everything is dynamic types, evaluated at runtime, and casting is actually just calling functions(for example (int) is actually the same as a call to parseInt, while (string) is the same as calling an objects __toString() method).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I checked it further and the `$byte_val` contains the bytes, exactly as they appear on the database. The error is somewhere on `$bc_val = bcadd(bcmul("$bc_val", "256", 0), "$byte_val", 0);` I am 100% sure about this.

Comment: While this is true my concert was about the edianness, see my code would work fine if the number is Big-endian, but the bytes of the number would be back to front for a little-endian number. Try replacing the for loop with: `for ($j = 7; $j >= 0; --$j) {` to see if little endian works better.

Answer (score 2):

Change your query as follows:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT cast(data as char(40)) FROM list WHERE id=".$id);
```

Comment: I get Undefined index: data on line `$list = str_split($mysql_array["data"], 8);`

Comment: @Luka Goodness, `cast(data as char(40)) as data` use an alias to get it.

Comment: I am getting the same result as the code I posted above